# Distribution Weibull

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to find the parameters of the weibull distribution, the only thing that they gave me were the mean=EX=40 and the standard deviation=VX=35^2 I have gotten there so far but I'm stuck, have any idea of how to solve for beta and delta.  The values are supposed to be beta=1.14566 and delta=41.98348

[image]

Comment: Can you use EXCEL or you would need mathematical solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to solve it using EXCEL and its numerical method of solving for beta.  Hopefully it is useful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With $\widehat{\mu}$ and $\widehat{\sigma}^2$ representing the sample mean and sample variance ("EX" and "VX"), as you indicate:

$\widehat{\mu} = \delta\ \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)$

$\widehat{\sigma}^2 =
 \delta^2 \ \left\{ \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{2}{\beta}\right) - 
\left[ \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right) \right]^2 \right\}$

Dividing $\widehat{\sigma}^2$ by $\widehat{\mu}^2$ yields:

$\displaystyle{\frac{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{2}{\beta}\right) }{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right) } = \frac{\widehat{\sigma}^2}{\widehat{\mu}^2}} \doteq{\xi(\beta)}$

$\beta$ would have to be solved numerically (e.g. Excel solver):

$\beta = \xi^{-1}\left(
\displaystyle{\frac{\widehat{\sigma}^2}{\widehat{\mu}^2}}
\right)$

Then you could solve for $\delta$ by substitution:

$\delta = \displaystyle{\frac{\widehat{\mu}}{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right) }}$